# CallerId of OrganizationServiceProxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm

I am making a external service which will create a record in **Order** entity of Dynamics 365 with the default field(e.g: created by and some default fields) will be named after the user who wants to create.

For that I tried using the **CallerId** property on the **OrganizationServiceProxy** class. I am setting the CallerId property by the user of CRM who is actually wanting to create a record. But I’m only able to create record if the user of crm has **System Administrator** role.

Some block of code is added for better understanding:

```
public void Get(Guid userId)
{
    var proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(c.ServiceUri), null, crmCredentials, null);
    proxy.EnableProxyTypes();
    var context = new OrganizationContext(proxy);

    // now setting caller id
    proxy.CallerId = userId;

    // generating order entity
    var t = new SalesOrder();
    t.Name = "Demo";
    .....
    ...
    .

    context.AddObject(t);
    context.SaveChanges(); // getting exceptions for normal user on save changes
}
```

Now my question is how to overcome the exception if the user of crm is not privileged with **System Administrator** role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify if any of the security role assigned to that “normal user” has create privilege granted on minimum user level (orange pie) for “Order” entity (sales order) under “Sales” tab. I guess not.

Give that privilege & verify the same code execution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine as long as the user that you are setting as CallerId has the **Sales Manager** Security Role. The user you are logging in with must also have at least a **Sales Manager** Security Role and the **Act on Behalf of Another User** privilege that can be found under Business Management tab.